# XmlResolver not called with XslCompiledTransform

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to resolve document function references in an XslCompiledTransform using a custom XmlResolver rather than actual files on the file system.  Using the obsolete XslTransform I can get it working fine, but not with the compiled transform (which I want to use for performance reasons).

The source XML document looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<StackOverflow>
</StackOverflow>
```

The XSLT looks like this:

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet version=""1.0""
                xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform""
                xmlns:xs=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema""
                exclude-result-prefixes=""xs"">
    <xsl:variable name=""author"" select=""document('data.xml')""/>

    <xsl:template match=""/"">
        <StackOverflow>
            <Author>
                <xsl:copy-of select=""$author/Person/*""/>
            </Author>
        </StackOverflow>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The expected output is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<StackOverflow>
 <Author>
  <FirstName>Aaron</FirstName>
  <LastName>Janes</LastName>
 </Author>
</StackOverflow>
```

The portion I want to use the custom XmlResolver for is the "document('data.xml')" which I do not want to load from a file on disk but, for brevity and simplicity in this post, from a static dictionary within the resolver, like so:

```cs
namespace transform
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml;

    public class XmlStaticResolver : XmlResolver
    {
        private const string PersonXml = 
@"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Person>
    <FirstName>Aaron</FirstName>
    <LastName>Janes</LastName>
</Person>";

        private readonly IDictionary<string, string> _input;

        public XmlStaticResolver()
        {
            _input = new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "data.xml", PersonXml }
            };
        }

        public override object GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, 
                                         string role, 
                                         Type ofObjectToReturn)
        {
            var host = absoluteUri.Host;
            var xml = _input[host];
            var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
            var result = new MemoryStream(bytes);

            return result;
        }

        public override Uri ResolveUri(Uri baseUri, string relativeUri)
        {
            return new Uri("static://" + relativeUri);
        }
    }
}
```

The resolver takes the relative URI ("data.xml") and prepends a fake protocol so that the GetEntity method considers "data.xml" as the URL's host.  Then the value is looked up in the static dictionary and returned as a memory stream for the transform to use.

When I use this method using the obsolete XmlTransform, it works exactly as expected, for example, calling the Transform method with the aforementioned XSLT and XML gets the expected result:

```cs
namespace transform
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.XPath;
    using System.Xml.Xsl;

    public class ObsoleteTransform
    {
        public string Transform(string xslt, string xml)
        {
            var resolver = new XmlStaticResolver();
            var transform = new XslTransform { XmlResolver = resolver };
            using (var transformReader = CreateXmlReader(new StringReader(xslt), resolver))
            {
                transform.Load(transformReader);
            }

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var xwriter = CreateXmlWriter(writer))
                {
                    using (var inputReader = new StringReader(xml))
                    {
                        var input = new XPathDocument(inputReader);
                        transform.Transform(input, 
                                            new XsltArgumentList(), 
                                            xwriter);
                    }
                }

                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static XmlReader CreateXmlReader(TextReader reader, 
                                                 XmlResolver resolver)
        {
            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                XmlResolver = resolver
            };

            var xreader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings, (string)null);
            return xreader;
        }

        private static XmlWriter CreateXmlWriter(TextWriter writer)
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                IndentChars = " ",
                NewLineChars = "\r\n"
            };

            var xwriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings);
            return xwriter;
        } 
    }
}
```

However, when I attempt to use the XslCompiledTransform I get an exception:

```
System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: 
    An error occurred while loading document 'data.xml'.
```

The code I am using to attempt the transform with the XslCompiledTransform is:

```cs
namespace transform
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.XPath;
    using System.Xml.Xsl;

    public class CompiledTransform
    {
        public string Transform(string xslt, string xml)
        {
            var resolver = new XmlStaticResolver();
            var xsltSettings = new XsltSettings(true, true);
            var transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
            using (var transformReader = CreateXmlReader(new StringReader(xslt), resolver))
            {
                transform.Load(transformReader, xsltSettings, resolver);
            }

            using (var writer = new StringWriter())
            {
                using (var xwriter = CreateXmlWriter(writer))
                {
                    using (var inputReader = new StringReader(xml))
                    {
                        var input = new XPathDocument(inputReader);
                        transform.Transform(input, 
                                            new XsltArgumentList(), 
                                            xwriter);
                    }
                }

                return writer.ToString();
            }
        }

        private static XmlReader CreateXmlReader(TextReader reader, 
                                                 XmlResolver resolver)
        {
            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings
            {
                XmlResolver = resolver
            };

            var xreader = XmlReader.Create(reader, settings, (string)null);
            return xreader;
        }

        private static XmlWriter CreateXmlWriter(TextWriter writer)
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
            {
                Indent = true,
                IndentChars = " ",
                NewLineChars = "\r\n"
            };

            var xwriter = XmlWriter.Create(writer, settings);
            return xwriter;
        } 
    }
}
```

It seems to me that, using the compiled transform, the resolver is not being called.  Does anyone have any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing your `XmlStaticResolver resolver` to *both* `XmlReader.Create()` *and* `XslCompiledTransform.Load()`.  You return your `PersonXml`/`data.xml`, i.e. XML, in both cases.  But `XslCompiledTransform.Load()` calls `XmlStaticResolver.ResolveUri()` with Uris for the *stylesheet* to resolve, i.e. paths to `.xslt` files.  At any rate, I don't see that you want to be passing your `XmlStaticResolver resolver` to `CreateXmlReader(new StringReader(xslt), resolver))` which is reading XSL; I do not know how it worked in old code....

I think you will find that your error `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: An error occurred while loading document 'data.xml'.` is telling you it is failing on trying to load `data.xml` as a *stylesheet* document, not as the XML document!

You say "It seems to me that, using the compiled transform, the resolver is not being called", but assuming you can debug just breakpoint your `XmlStaticResolver.ResolveUri()` and see where it is called and with what arguments.